# Mapping single key (such as 'F1') to multiple keys (such as 'Ctrl+C') in Gnome

Tags: linux, desktop, gnome

I know how to map a single key to a command using the gconf settings.  I also know how to map a single key to another key ('F1' -> 'CTRL') using Xmodmap.  My question is how can I map a single key such as 'F1' to a multi-key operation such at 'Ctrl+C'.  I am basically trying to set up a single key to simulate copy.  I can think of two ways to possibly do this:

- Map single key to multiple keys so that when the single key is pressed it is essentially pressing 'Ctrl+C'
- Use gconf settings to execute the copy "command" upon the single key press.  I am not sure if there is a "command" to copy text.